# Why are Java primitive types' modifiers public, abstract, and final?

Tags: java, reflection

In the process of doing some reflection on Java types, I came across an oddity that I do not understand.

Inspecting `int` for its modifiers returns `public`, `abstract`, and `final`. I understand `public` and `final`, but the presence of `abstract` on a primitive type is non-obvious to me. Why is this the case?

Edit: I am not reflecting on `Integer` but on `int`:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;

public class IntegerReflection {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println(String.format("int.class == Integer.class -> %b", int.class == Integer.class));
        System.out.println(String.format("int.class modifiers: %s", Modifier.toString(int.class.getModifiers())));
        System.out.println(String.format("Integer.class modifiers: %s", Modifier.toString(Integer.class.getModifiers())));
    }
}
```

The output when run:

```
int.class == Integer.class -> false
int.class modifiers: public abstract final
Integer.class modifiers: public final
```

Comment: Because you cannot instantiate perhaps?

Comment: How exactly are you getting these values? It's not `int` you're inspecting, but `Integer`

Comment: `Integer` is not `abstract`...

Comment: @OscarRyz I know, I was answering to Denis Tulskiy.

Comment: Primitive types are not classes. However classes for those types are provided to be able to get information for class fields that are primitive types via reflection. Abstract just means these cannot be instantiated.

Comment: @oconnor0: See my answer.  I think it makes the most sense and is comprehensive!  Very cool question, by the way.  Very intriguing stuff.

Comment: @FlorentGuillaume: yeah, my guess was wrong :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run

```
System.out.println(Modifier.toString(int.class.getModifiers()));
```

you get

```
public abstract final
```

possibly because you can't sub-class it - i.e. final, and you can't instantiate it - i.e. abstract.

From Oracle's [Abstract Methods and Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)

> Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but they can be subclassed.

The fact is its also final means it cannot be sub-classes.

Comment: Hmmm... seems like the only correct answer so far and got a downvote without explanation. I will give it +1.

Comment: if you try to debug int.class.newinstance, you'll see creation of NoSuchMethodException("int.<init>()"), that is this class is not instantiable because it has no constructors. I think the fact it is abstract means nothing.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov It means primitives cannot be instantiated.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey yes abstract class cannot be instantiated but the int.class, specifically, cannot be instantiated because it has no constructors. The property "is abstract" is not checked, that's why I said it means nothing. Of course it is related to the Sun (Oracle) implementation, other JVM could check "is abstract" first.

Comment: As far as i can tell the question was _Why_ .

Answer (score 7):

According to the [JLS 8.1.1.1 - Abstract Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.1):

> An abstract class is a class that is incomplete, or to be considered incomplete.

By definition, there can be no instances of `int.class`.  You can't compile this kind of code:

```
int a = new int();
```

There are no constructors for `int`.  There are no objects created.  `int.class` does not even extend `Object`.  If you run the following line of code, you will get `null` as the result.

```
System.out.println(int.class.getSuperclass());
```

So because you can never have a true instance of the `int.class`, it is by definition `abstract`.  Also, according to the [Integer API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#TYPE), the `Integer.TYPE` field (which holds `int.class`) is a class which only *represents* the primitive type.

This is proven by the following code:

```
int a = 4;
System.out.println(int.class.isInstance(a));
```

This returns `false`.

As such, `int.class` is likely just used in the system for representation purposes, as said in the `Integer` API.  The fact that there is also a `void.class` type but no `null.class` type makes me think that this is used primarily with Reflection.  This is just conjecture, though.

---

If anyone is interested, the `int.class` essentially contains nothing that the reflection package recognizes and is likely just a dummy class.  If you run the following code, you will see that it has no constructors, no fields, and no methods.

```
Method[] intMethods = int.class.getMethods();

if(intMethods.length == 0) {
    System.out.println("No methods.");
}
else {
    for(Method method : intMethods) {
        System.out.println(method.getName());
    }
}

Constructor[] intConstructors = int.class.getConstructors();

if(intConstructors.length == 0) {
    System.out.println("No constructors.");
}
else {
    for(Constructor constructor: intConstructors) {
        System.out.println(constructor.getName());
    }
}

Field[] intFields = int.class.getFields();

if(intFields.length == 0) {
    System.out.println("No fields.");
}
else {
    for(Field field: intFields) {
        System.out.println(field.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### From JVM Specifications:

> An abstract class is a class that is incomplete, or **considered** incomplete. 
>   Only abstract classes may have abstract methods, that is,
>   methods that are declared but not yet implemented.
>
> A class can be declared final if its definition is complete and no subclasses are desired or > required. Because a final class never has
>   any subclasses, the methods of a final class cannot be overridden in a
>   subclass. A class cannot be both final and abstract, because the
>   implementation of such a class could never be completed.

According to [specifications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/ClassFile.doc.html#75734) a class cannot be both Abstract and Final. *But* however, it seems like JVM does not treat primitive types as classes, which is technically correct since primitive types are **not** classes and are supplied to the language runtime by the JVM(using `Class getPrimitiveClass(const char *name)`).

So `int`, and every other primitive type,

```
> a. Should be accessible from within the language: Make it `public` 
> b. Should not be extensible                     : Make it `final` 
> c. Should not be instantiated with `new`        : Make it `abstract`.
```

My theory from the JVM specification for why primitive types are `abstract` is because, they're **considered** incomplete.

Comment: Should not be instantiated with `new`        : Make it `abstract`. > Actually you can create anonymous classes with a new AbstractClass(){...}

Answer (score 1):

`int.class` is also accessible as `Integer.TYPE` and is the Class instance representing the primitive type `int`.

Given that you cannot instantiate an object of this class (because ints are not instances, they are primitive types), I think it makes sense to have the type marked `abstract`.

At the moment I can't find a reference to that in the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html) though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is just a special mark for `primitive class` different from `normal class`.

JVM code implementation:

```
mirror::Class* ClassLinker::InitializePrimitiveClass(ObjPtr<mirror::Class> primitive_class,
                                                     Primitive::Type type) {

  Handle<mirror::Class> h_class(hs.NewHandle(primitive_class));
  // public final static
  h_class->SetAccessFlags(kAccPublic | kAccFinal | kAccAbstract);
  h_class->SetPrimitiveType(type);
  h_class->SetIfTable(GetClassRoot(kJavaLangObject)->GetIfTable());

  // ...
  return h_class.Get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why are Java primitive types' modifiers public, abstract, and final?

The Java 11 [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getModifiers()) for `Class.getModifiers()` states:

> *If the underlying class is an array class, then its `public`, `private` and `protected` modifiers are the same as those of its component type. If this `Class` represents a primitive type or `void`, its `public` modifier is always true, and its `protected` and `private` modifiers are always false. If this object represents an array class, a primitive type or `void`, then its `final` modifier is always true and its `interface` modifier is always false. **The values of its other modifiers are not determined by this specification**.*

So the javadoc is specifying that primitive types are `public` and `final`.  This makes intuitive sense.  That will be the reason for the choice in those two cases.

Technically, `abstract` on a primitive type make no sense.  A primitive type is not a class, and is not instantiable using `new`.  However, given the way that other Java APIs work (e.g. reflective method lookup), it is necessary to have `Class` objects that represent all Java types.  Therefore, `Integer.TYPE` == `int.class` and similar need to exist.

Anyway, for whatever reason, the spec is saying "unspecified" for the `abstract` modifier on a `Class` that represents a primitive type.

However, the `Class` modifiers are represented as bits in an integer, and JVM implementation has to return a value for the "abstract" bit position in that integer.  While neither choice (1 or 0) has any meaning according to the spec, it was / is better<sup>1</sup> for one of the Java engineers (probably back in the 1990's) to choose<sup>2</sup> a specific value for the bit in the primitive type case than to (say) randomly return 1 or 0 at runtime.

So the bottom line is:

- The choice for `abstract` is (or could be) entirely arbitrary, so don't ascribe any meaning to it.
- If you rely on the current behavior for the `abstract` but, there is a *theoretical* risk that your code will break in a future version of Java ... if they change the behavior.

---

<sup>1 - In my opinion it is better because it is easier for users of the `Class` API to have deterministic behavior than non-deterministic behavior.  And it is most likely simpler to implement it this way.

2 - We most likely will never know for sure why the specific choice was made.  Maybe someone tossed a coin?  It doesn't matter.</sup>

Answer (score -2):

if you reflected into a class that inherited from an abstract class, and then tried to dig into the base class for that instance, a property defined as abstract in the abstract class would have no value, but it is part of the class definition.

Heres an example:

```
public class absBase{

    private string name;
    private int ID;

    public abstract int GetID();
}

public class concreteClass:absBase{
    @Override
    public int GetID(){
        return ID + 1;
    }
}
```

so if you were reflecting absBase, and looked at GetID, it would have to be abstract by definition, if you looked at concreteClass.GetID() however it would be public.
hope that helps.